# How to Include a file in all the templates in Django

Tags: django, django-templates

Basically I have a running project with more number of templates.

Now i have a situation where i have to include a new django template file in all the existing templates.

It seems that including it in each and every template using inclusion tag is more time consuming and inefficient way.

So i want to know is there an any alternative way i can make this django template file available inside all the templates.

Sorry for my sloppy english.

Comment: Are you using a base template??

Comment: @jathanism... ya i do use base tempate.... but there are some templates which doesn't extend base template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a block in your base template, where you include your file (just once):

In base.html:

```
{% block including_file %}
    {% include "my_file.html" %}
{% endblock %}
```

An then make all of your other templates extend your base template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
```

**EDIT:** If you have some templates that don't extend the base template, you can do a generic base template just with the `{% block including_file %}` and nothing else. This way, `base.html` extends `generic_base.html` and templates that don't extend `base.html` can now just extend `generic_base.html`.

Comment: @julio.algeria Thanks for your answer.But i have more files  which doesn't extends base template.So manually extending base template and block out other unwanted parts will consume more time and prone to error..

Comment: @shiva: Yes, that's why I edited my answer. The solution is to create a "previous" base template (I called `generic_base.html`). This generic base will have only the block including the file you want in every template. `base.html` will extend this generic base (so now every template that extends `base.html` has the included file) and the templates that doesn't extend `base.html` will have to extend `generic_base.html`.